# Was Russia or the USSR ever involved in a large military embarrassment alongside or against Vietnam?

Tags: soviet-union, war, russia, vietnam

I was listening to a Russian politician's (2021, pre-war) declaration of what would happen with the current war in Ukraine, and I was caught offguard by him mentioning a Russian military-related embarrassment in Vietnam.

Here's the video; around a minute in:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OutvYSl_TLc&t=60s

> *[Despite Russian Government propoganda to it's own people,]* Whatever
> happens *[in this war with Ukraine]*, in any case, will end in a
> horrible defeat and tragedy for Russia. To add to the
> [Afghan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet%E2%80%93Afghan_War),
> **Vietnam**, [Chechen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Chechen_War), [our] poor
> country will grow yet another hump of shame.
>
> [The translation into English may be faulty, but the word "Vietnam" can be clearly discerned audibly]

**What Vietnam "lump of shame" might he be referring to?**

I'm aware Russia armed Vietnam (alongside China) in the USA-Vietnam war. But Vietnam won that war. And Russia, as far as I know, doesn't have much to be embarrassed about there, and didn't face much blowback, as far as I know.

Plus, the way the politician is talking, it seems he is referring to Russia *directly* making greatly humiliating military blunders.

Comment: There was the Chinese invasion of Vietnam in 1979, where [the Soviets refused to take any direct action to defend their ally.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Vietnamese_War#:~:text=However%2C%20the%20Soviets%20refused%20to%20take%20any%20direct%20action%20to%20defend%20their%20ally.) Doesn't seem like it would be on the same scale as the other two though.

Comment: Nevzorov is not a politician but a journalist.

Comment: I think what is implied is the French and the American defeats in Vietnam, which are similar to the Soviet (and later American) failure in Afghanistan. It is simply poorly formulated.

Comment: @RogerVadim - It likely makes more sense in the original Russian.

Comment: I think the deputy meant that Vietnam is an embarassing event for someone, (here the US) as Afghanistan is for USSR ans USA, or Checheny for Russia

Comment: @T.E.D. No, it does not. It definitely parses as "Russia did something shameful in Vietnam". Maybe he means USSR supporting North Vietnam was unethical or something.